# How to return a string in c# as soon as called.?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, google-visualization

This is a sample of google charts.. I am using c#.net.. What should I do in C# to return a string in place of getData.php here..

```
function drawChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "getData.php",
          dataType:"json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;
```

I have tried to work it out using class but it didn't worked.. Can web service be used or is their any other way for that..

Comment: So you have a ASP.NET page written in C# that generates JavaScript and you want to dynamically insert a piece of JSON into that?

Comment: yes.. i have a json string.. but don't know how to work out with this function..

Comment: `var jsonData = <%= myJsonString %>;`?

Comment: you want to have C# code similar with this jquery code?

Comment: Sorry, I meant i had grabbed data form the database and have converted it into json.. so how shall i pass it to this function.. i tried web service but didn't worked..

Comment: which web service you did try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your JavaScript code like this.

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "MyWebService.asmx/GetData",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;
```

Create a web-service called *MyWebService.asmx* and in it's code-behind write,

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class MyWebService: System.Web.Services.WebService 
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string GetData()
    {
        return "your desired string";
    }
}
```